# Checking if file is larger than 1 MB

Tags: php, mysql, file, size

I would like to ask your help. I wrote a code which checks if all the fields are filled in and if the file is not larger than 1 MB. If everything is correct the file successfuly uploads to MySQL database. But if the file size is larger than 1 MB the code stops working. The error doesnt show up and all the fields become empty. Here`s the code (some of it is in Lithuanian, sorry):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])){ 
    include 'config.php';
    $username = $_SESSION['login'];
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $rws = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $autorius = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['autorius']);$pavadinimas = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['pavadinimas']);$puslapiai = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['puslapiai']);$tema = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['tema']);$pmintis = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['pmintis']);$pveikejai = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['pveikejai']);$aveikejai = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['aveikejai']);$epizodas = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['epizodas']);$nuomone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['nuomone']);$apie = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['apie']);$foto = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['foto']);$user_id = $rws['id'];
    if (!empty($autorius) && !empty($pavadinimas) && !empty($puslapiai) && !empty($tema) && !empty($pmintis) && !empty($pveikejai) && !empty($aveikejai) && !empty($epizodas) && !empty($nuomone) && !empty($apie) && isset($foto) && $_FILES['foto']['size'] > 0 && $_FILES['foto']['size'] < 1000001) {
        $fileName = $_FILES['foto']['name'];$tmpName  = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];$fileSize = $_FILES['foto']['size'];$fileType = $_FILES['foto']['type'];
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $foto = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $foto = addslashes($foto);
        fclose($fp);
        $query = "INSERT INTO books (id_user, autorius, pavadinimas, puslapiai, tema, pmintis, pveikejai, aveikejai, epizodas, nuomone, apie, foto, name, type, size) ".
        "VALUES ('$user_id', '$autorius', '$pavadinimas', '$puslapiai', '$tema', '$pmintis', '$pveikejai', '$aveikejai', '$epizodas', '$nuomone', '$apie', '$foto', '$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize')";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
        $success = "Knygos aprašymas įkeltas";
        echo $_FILES['foto']['size'];
    }
    else if (empty($autorius) || empty($pavadinimas) || empty($puslapiai) || empty($tema) || empty($pmintis) || empty($pveikejai) || empty($aveikejai) || empty($epizodas) || empty($nuomone) || empty($apie)) {
        $error = "Užpildykite visus laukelius!";
    }
    else if (empty($foto)){
        $error = "Pasirinkite viršelio nuotrauką!";
    }
    else if ($_FILES['foto']['size'] > 1000001){
        $error = "Viršelio nuotraukos dydid neturi viršyti 1 MB!";
    }
    }
?>
<?php include 'bin/includes/header.html'; ?>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Įkelti knygos aprašymą
                    <small>Ikelkite savo knygos aprašymą</small>
                </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Pagrindinis</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">Įkelti knygos aprašymą</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form name="upload" id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <?php
                        if(isset($success)) {
                            echo '<label style="color: #44FF00;">';
                            echo $success;
                            echo '</label>';
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<label style="color: #FF3700;">';
                            echo $error;
                            echo '</label>';
                        } ?>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="autorius" maxlength="60" placeholder="Autorius" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['autorius'])) echo $_POST['autorius'];?>">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pavadinimas" maxlength="255" placeholder="Pavadinimas" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['pavadinimas'])) echo $_POST['pavadinimas'];?>">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="puslapiai" placeholder="Puslapių skaičius" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['puslapiai'])) echo $_POST['puslapiai'];?>">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pveikejai" maxlength="999" placeholder="Pagrindiniai veikėjai" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['pveikejai'])) echo $_POST['pveikejai'];?>">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="aveikejai" maxlength="999" placeholder="Antraeiliai veikėjai" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['aveikejai'])) echo $_POST['aveikejai'];?>">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea placeholder="Tema" rows="2" class="form-control" name="tema" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"><?php if(!empty($_POST['tema'])) echo $_POST['tema'];?></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea placeholder="Pagrindinė mintis" rows="2" class="form-control" name="pmintis" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"><?php if(!empty($_POST['pmintis'])) echo $_POST['pmintis'];?></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea placeholder="Siužetas" rows="5" class="form-control" name="apie" maxlength="2999" style="resize:none"><?php if(!empty($_POST['apie'])) echo $_POST['apie'];?></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea placeholder="Įsimintiniausias epizodas" rows="3" class="form-control" name="epizodas" maxlength="2999" style="resize:none"><?php if(!empty($_POST['epizodas'])) echo $_POST['epizodas'];?></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea placeholder="Nuomonė apie knygą" rows="3" class="form-control" name="nuomone" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"><?php if(!empty($_POST['nuomone'])) echo $_POST['nuomone'];?></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Įkelti viršelį (max 1MB)</label>
                            <input name="foto" type="file" id="foto"> 
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Įkelti</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php include 'bin/includes/footer.html'; ?>
<?php } else {
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you set file upload limit?

Comment: What is your question?  If you want to prevent an error, check the file size in PHP.  Or, are you trying to get around the limit?

Comment: I`ve set so if the file is over the limit a message is echo`ed. But it doesn`t echo the message and the info that the user has input disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this to get the file size:

`$size = filesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);`

This returns the filesize in **byte**. One MB are **1048576** bytes. You should check for the function not returning false.

In general: You should use exceptions for this purpose, it is much simplier to check for a condition and then check again. If you just want to use if-else-statements, you should rearrange it (check for errors first and then upload the thing in the else-case).

Why are you not saving the files in filesystem? This is a lot easier...

Comment: The text that is in the field still disappears and the error doesn`t get echo`ed

Comment: @DziugasVysniauskas: Make this: `die(var_dump($_FILES, filesize($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'])));` directly after `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {`.

Comment: @DziugasVysniauskas: Sorry, one `)` more please.

Comment: All the styles are gone now, just this

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty
boolean false

Comment: Then, `$_FILES` is not set at this time. You should make another if-statement like `if(isset($_FILES['foto']))` instead if just checking if something has been transferred via POST.

Comment: Nope, still doesn`t work. If a file is over 1 MB all the info in the fields disappears.